# Counterexample for $ F \subset (f^{-1}(F)) $?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Someone gave an example along the lines of  $f(x)=x^2$ might work where $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, but I don't see how this is true. Would greatly appreciate any form of help!

Comment: You completely changed the question. Is this in fact the one you want to ask about? Is $F$ in the domain and codomain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$.

Consider $F\stackrel{\rm def}{=}(-\infty,0]$ (for instance). Then $f^{-1}(F) = \{0\}$ (can you see why?)
But $$F=(-\infty,0]\not\subseteq \{0\}=f^{-1}(F).$$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Let me see if I get this right: $f^{-1}(F)=0$ because $f(x)=x^2$ can only take on positive values and 0. So 0 is the only one that works. Would this example work as a counterexample for $E \supseteq f^{-1}(f(E))$ and $f( \cap_{E \in \epsilon} E) \supseteq  \cap_{E \in \epsilon}  f(E)$ as well?

Comment: It's hard to decipher from my phone (comments are not rendered), but if I get the first Latex commands correctly, it does give a counterexample for the first. (I cannot parse the second)

Comment: Thanks! I might end up posting my second as a separate question. It involves taking the function of union of a collection of subsets and showing it is not a subset of the union of a collection of subsets of the function.

Answer (score 1):

No, for $f: A\rightarrow B$ and $F\subset B$, one has, in general, $f(f^{-1}(F))=F\cap f(A)\subset F$. So, for a counterexample, any $F$ not included in $f(A)$ can do.

Comment: My mistake. The statement I wrote earlier was true. I was looking to show that  $ F \supseteq (f^{-1}(F)) $ is not true.

Comment: @Nikitau OK, I modified my answer.